# Does Nutch automatically crawl my site when new pages are added?

Tags: nutch

Does [Nutch](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/) crawl automatically when I add new pages to the website?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to recrawl or create the index from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Tt wont re-crawl automatically. You can do either of these:

1. make the parent page of the new url re-crawled so that the new url enters the crawldb and will be fetched in subsequent fetch round.
2. Add the new url directly to the crawldb via inject command.

Answer (score 0):

You should do scheduled crawling to keep your data up-to-date.

[Open source Java Job Schedulers](http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers)